# Appgyver: How to use Ionic Icons or images in super-navbar?

Tags: steroids

I am trying to use navigation images on left as well right of `<super-navbar>` but it is stated in the official documentation, that only text is supported in super-navbar buttons. But there must be some way around to do this. Below is my code, where I want to place images instead of text:

```
<super-navbar>
    <super-navbar-button side="left" id="hamburger" onclick="supersonic.ui.drawers.open()">Menu</super-navbar-button>
    <super-navbar-title>MyApp</super-navbar-title>
    <super-navbar-button side="right">Search</super-navbar-button>
  </super-navbar>
```

Instead of "menu" text I want to have hamburger type icon or png image at least. Same for search text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished right now by removing the `<super-navbar>` section and writing your own html header.

If you look in the layout file for your project there is an import statement as you mentioned:

`<link rel="import" href="/components/supersonic/components/import.html">`

There is a section that states:

`* @name super-navbar-button`

`* When used inside the``element, creates a button that will be displayed on the navigation bar. Only text content is supported for the button title.`

Support for icons has been requested. You can subscribe to their github to get notifications of issues. https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids

One work around to be able to keep using `<super-navbar>` and have icons is to use something like this which will render as ≡

```
<super-navbar-button ng-click="toggleMenuDrawer()">
    &equiv;
</super-navbar-button>
```

They have a good forum on Muut as well. [This issue](https://muut.com/appgyver#!/steroids-native-ui:navbar-disappearing-after-i) is most likely related to trying to add icons in the `<super-navbar>`. I experienced a disappearing navbar after trying to add markup: `<i class="icon super-search"></i>`
It works in the main content area, but makes the navbar behave differently when nested in a `<super>` element.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the link to the issue where support for icons has been requested?

Comment: One reference to icons in the navbar is [here](https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids/issues/241)

Another is [here](https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids/issues/391)